# Who is Thyagaraja?

Tags: saint

Who is [Thyagaraja](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tyagaraja) to Hinduism?

Is he a poet or rishi or jivanmukta or avaduta or  avatar etc.,?

Comment: The wikipedia article had clearly described who Thyagaraja was.  Your question is not clear?@hanugm

Comment: @srimannarayanakv What did it say?

Comment: He was one of the greatest  3 musicians in South India and later a saint.@hanugm